# how to hide some properties using ABPeoplePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abpeoplepickerview

When using `peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person`, a view with all of the contact's information is shown. I've seen apps which only display selected info only (e.g. phone numbers).

How can I do this? I only want to display the contact's name and phone numbers.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty simple.  I customized ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to only show email addresses.

The code looks like this:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    [peoplePicker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
    [peoplePicker setDisplayedProperties:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty]]];
```

You can find a list of the available properties [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can,

You could do this to get a list of people for the address book:

```
// get the default address book. 
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

and then create your own custom picker view, showing only the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you simply do this.

```
var people = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
people.peoplePickerDelegate = self
// 3 is for Phone Number
people.displayedProperties = [3]
```